# Where can I set advanced settings (like fast_reauth) in network-manager?

Tags: linux-mint, networkmanager, settings

Is there any possibility to change *"advanced"* default settings in Linux Mint's `network-manager` (like `fast_reauth=0`)?

I can see that there are config files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, but I'm not sure where to add it exactly and if it's possible at all (without using `wicd` or `wpa_supplicant`, but maybe adding something in `modprobe.d` or whereever).

```
# just in case...

$ dpkg -s network-manager | grep Version
Version: 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1

$ uname -mrs
Linux 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
```